# SPSS Randomly select a number from a respondent's input

Tags: random, spss

I'm hoping there is SPSS syntax that I can use to randomly select a number from among a couple of variables. For example: the data lists the ages of respondent's children in four variables - Age1 Age2 Age3 Age4

```
Resp 1: 3 6 8 
Resp 2: 2 10 
Resp 3: 4
```

I want to create a variable that stores a randomly selected age for each respondent - something like:

```
Resp 1: 6 
Resp 2: 2 
Resp 3: 4
```

The code I'm using at the moment:

```
COUNT kids=age1 to age4 (1 thru 16).  
COMPUTE rand=RND(RV.UNIFORM(1, kids),1).  
DO REPEAT  
x1=age1 to age4  
/x2=1 to 4.  
IF (rand=x2) random_age=x1.  
END REPEAT.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?

Comment: David, I created a variable that counts the number of valid answers. I then created a variable with a random universal number up to the count variable value. In the third variable I matched the random number to input to derive the age associated with it. It works, but it's not very elegant....

Comment: Please edit your post and add your original code - this will make it easier to understand where the problem is and what we can help with -gotta make sure the new code I suggest is more elegant than the one you already have ;)

Comment: so, just saw your edit - I see the code I suggested is basically identical to yours... Sorry - I can't think of a simpler or more elegant solution. Anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggested code for the task.

First creating some sample data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/id age1 to age4 (5f2).
begin data
1, 4, 5, 6, 7
2, 4, 5, 6,
3, 6, 7,,  
4, 8,,,   
5, 5, 6, 7, 
6, 10,,,
end data.
```

Now to randomly select one of the ages:

```
compute numages=4-nmiss(age1 to age4).
compute SelectThis = rnd(uniform(numages)+.5).
do repeat ag=age1 to age4 /ind=1 to 4.
    if SelectThis=ind SelectedRandAge=ag.
end repeat.
exe.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's my attempt for the time being:

```
data list list /age1 to age4.
begin data.
10 9 5 8
3
13 15
1 4 5
4 7 8 2
end data.
count valid=age1 to age4 (lo thru hi).
compute s=trunc(1+uniform(valid)).
vector age=age1 to age4.
compute myvar=age(s).
list age1 to age4 myvar.
```

Comment: +1 for the new solution! Note, though, that the advantage of your solution is that it doesn't require a loop at all. It will still work if you replace the  `loop - end loop` sequence with this: `compute myvar=age(s).` - which makes the code shorter and more elegant.

Comment: Thanks. I went too fast. ;)

Comment: You might as well edit your post (useful for OP and future users)

Comment: Done. Thanks again.